# API call returns full response in Postman but only first instance of json object using requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I am making a simple GET request, when these requests are made through postman I get the full response. However, when making the same requests via Python using requests lib I only get a single instance of object "user". The exact same code works jsut as expected when going to one of their other endpoints.

Postman result:

```
{
  "user": {
    //...
  },
  "user": {
    //...
  },
  //...
}
```

Python response.json():

```
{
  "user": {
     //...
  }
}
```

Code:

```
url = 'my_url'
auth = ('user', 'pass')

response = requests.get(url, auth=auth)
return response
```

I have walked through the response and URL is exact same as when I get the full response from Postman. Not sure what Im missing?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have two identical "user" keys in the returned object. Postman shows you the raw data returned, but when you call `response.json()` it parses the data and converts it to a python dictionary, which cannot have two identical keys in an object (same for JSON by the way).

Comment: Hmm ok, is there som solution? I have no control over what the API returns, its not mine.

Comment: You can use `response.content` or `response.text` which will give you the response as a string, but then you will have to parse it yourself.

Comment: Unfortunately as soon as I parse it, same issue occurs.

Comment: What do you mean by parse? Do you turn it into a dictionary?